# Is there a way to listen to an initialized object's method? Interactive Broker API connection object

Tags: java, listener, interactive, broker

I have below code tied to a Jbutton.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:


    m_client.eConnect("127.0.0.1", 4001, 1);
    if (m_client.isConnected()) {
        jButton1.setText("Connected");
        jButton1.setEnabled(false);

    }
}
```

Is there a way to constantly check if `m_client.isConnected()` is True or False, so if it is False I can `setEnable(true)` my `jButton1`.  I have searched some relevant information, they all point to a feature called 'LISTENER'? But I still did not figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

It's a java IB API's feature.

When TWS closes the sockets connection, or when TWS is shut down, the method [EWrapper#connectionClosed()](http://www.interactivebrokers.com/php/apiUsersGuide/apiguide/java/connectionclosed.htm) is invoked.

Pay attention to catch all exceptions coming both from the socket and from your code, otherwise TWS will close the connection unexpectedly.

Comment: Could you be more specific? How am I going to constantly check whether connectionClosed() is invoked?

Comment: You should have a class implementing `EWrapper` interface, and therefore overriding all its methods, including `connectionClosed()`

Comment: @hwen0419 It's an event. You just place an event handler and when disconnected the event will fire. For more help on IB API see also this nice specialized Linkedin group: http://www.linkedin.com/groups?home=&gid=4932221&trk=anet_ug_hm&goback=%2Egmr_4932221 "Interactive Brokers Traders"